# What are the most useful Intellij IDEA keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I did a bit of googling hoping to find a post on IDEA shortcuts similar to Jeff's post on Visual Studio shortcuts ([Visual Studio .NET 2003 and 2005 Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000315.html)), but didn't really spot anything that helped.  Hopefully the answers to this question will fill the void.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109067/is-a-list-of-x-without-best-still-inappropriate for some background on why its closed. I'll add I disagree with the current rule and would love for it to change. EIther by removing it or by adding a specific survey type question.

Comment: If you are coming from Eclipse, you can go to File -> settings -> KeyMap, and chose the "eclipse" mapping in the "Keymaps" drop down list. >This will map equivalent actions to their default Eclipse key combinations.

Comment: I understand the "Q & A site" Idea. However maybe a new Stack Exchange site could be create something like DeveloperTools.StackExchange. Then when people need help with there IDE, Debugger, or whatever Questions like this could go there instead.

Also maybe Questions like this instead of being "closed" should be converted to Wiki style questions.

Comment: I recommand you try emacsIDEAs plugin.  http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea_ce&pluginId=7163

Answer (score 214):

These are some of my most used keyboard short cuts

Syntax aware selection in the editor selects a word at the caret and then selects expanding areas of the source code. For example, it may select a method name, then the expression that calls this method, then the whole statement, then the containing block, etc.:
**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>**

Basic Code Completion, to complete methods, keywords etc.:
**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>**

Go to Declaration. Use this to navigate to the declaration of a class, method or variable used somewhere in the code:
**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>**

Introduce Variable Refactoring, to create a variable from an expression. This expression may even be incomplete or contain errors. Since version 8, IDEA intelligently selects a likely expression when no text is selected:
**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>**

Go to Class, to quickly open any class in the editor:
**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>**

To open any file, not just classes:
**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>**

Comment/Uncomment current line or selection:
**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>** and **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>**

Quick JavaDoc Popup to show the JavaDoc of the method or class at the text cursor:
**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>** (*<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>* on Mac OS X)

Smart Type Completion to complete an expression with a method call or variable with a type suitable in the current Context:
**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>**

Rename refactoring to rename any identifier. Can look in comments, text files and across different languages too:
**<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>**

Select in Popup to quickly select the currently edited element (class, file, method or field) in any view (Project View, Structure View or other): 
**<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>**

Highlight Usages in File. Position the text cursor on any identifier without selecting any text and it will show all places in the file where that variable, method etc. is used. Use it on a throws, try or catch keyword to show all places where the exception is thrown. Use it on the implements keyword to highlight the methods of the implemented interface:
**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>**

Comment: to undo highlighting with Ctrl+Shift+F7 use Escape

Answer (score 176):

By far my favourite all purpose shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

It does a search as you type through all the commands in intellij. Not only that but when you find the command you want it also displays the corresponding shortcut key next to it!

Answer (score 88):

Here are the Intellij IDEA keyboard shortcuts I find most useful (listed in roughly the order of usage for me):

The shortcut I use the most is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (Go to declaration), to see what a method does, where a variable is declared etc. This is almost always followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> to get back to where I was (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd> works to “go forward” again).

A related navigation shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, (Go to implementation). Press it when the caret is at the method name of an interface, and you get a pop-up list of all the places where this method is implemented, and you can select which one you want to go to (if there is only one implementation, you go straight there). The same goes for overridden methods.

The opposite of this is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> (Go to super-method/super-class). If the caret is at the implementation of a method in an interface (indicated by the little green interface-symbol in the left gutter), this shortcut takes you to the interface itself.

When I want to see all the places where a method or variable is used (which I want to do a lot), I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> (Show usages). This gives you a pop-up list of all the usages, and you can easily navigate to each one. I prefer this over <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> (Find usages), which gives you the same information, but in a separate pane below.

To find classes, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> (Go to class), which lets you search using only the capital letters in the class name (“camel humps”), and * as wildcard.

Yet another shortcut I use, both when reading and writing code, is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> (Parameter info) at the arguments of methods and constructors, to see the types and names of the parameters.

When it comes to writing code, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> (Basic code completion) a lot to auto-complete method names, variable names etc (or simply to see which methods are available for a certain object, by trying to auto-complete directly at the dot following the name of the object).

For searching in the current file I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> (Find - probably the least surprising shortcut in this list), <kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> (Find next/previous) to repeat the search, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> (Find in path) to search in the whole project.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (Select successively increasing code blocks) is handy when selecting chunks of code. Repeatedly pressing it selects more and more of the code. Useful when searching, indenting, commenting out code etc.

If there are errors in the file, <kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> (Next/previous highlighted error) will jump to them.

I use the sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>N</kbd> (Show Changes View) to see which files in the project I have modified compared to the subversion repository. To diff the current file against the version in the subversion repository, I use the sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> (Compare with the Same Repository Version). In the diff view, I use <kbd>F7</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> to navigate between the changes.

When not in the diff view, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> to jump to the parts of the file that have been changed compared to the checked-out version. At each modification point, you see the corresponding part in the checked-out version in a pop-up window.

Finally, I run JUnit tests using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Edit: One really useful shortcut that I've only started using in the last few months is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>. It brings up a pop-up with the 15 most recently used files, and you just arrow down to the one you want and hit enter to navigate to it.

Comment: I use Ctrl + tab for switching between recent files a lot.

Comment: For Changes, you can use alt+9 instead.

Answer (score 80):

According to the Jetbrains folks, it will have to be these, as they are for the one wearing the shirt: (Got that from Devoxx)

[image: promotionalshirt]

Comment: It's from Jetbrains - they brought these to Devoxx

Comment: This is how everybody (but the one who wears it) sees it - I think it's appropriate.

Comment: @Ray, https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/rotate-image/

Comment: @Ray, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jcoonajankpbolkgbipphpmbhefkengn and https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/rotate-images/

Answer (score 32):

Help\Productivity Guide

It tells you what are the shortcuts you use/don't use and displays usage statistics. It will guide you to the unknown features.

Answer (score 30):

Some of the time savers:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> : show intention actions (like Eclipse quick fix)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> : introduce variable (never type the left hand side of an assignment again)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> : smart completion ( [even two levels down since IntelliJ 8](http://blog.xebia.com/2008/11/11/intellij-8-even-smarter-code-completion/) )
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> : select succesively increasing code blocks. Kind of obvious but a real time saver!

The Canoo blog contains some [(+8) articles](http://www.canoo.com/blog/tag/idea/) on some more advanced IntelliJ keyboard shortcuts.

The *Key Promoter* and *Shortcut keys list* plugins are **really helpful** for (constantly) learning new IntelliJ keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Key promoter: http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=1003

Comment: Shortcut Keys List: http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=2391

Answer (score 22):

Try using the [Key Promoter](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=4455) plugin. That will help in learning the shortcuts.
Couple of shortcuts apart from the above suggestions:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd>: Works consistently to insert anything. (Add a new class, method etc)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>: Surround code block. Another useful stuff.

Answer (score 9):

This is probably dependent on your development environment, but when doing BlackBerry development I code in IntelliJ and still compile and debug through the BlackBerry JDE. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> is vital in this case as it allows you to copy the full path of the file you are currently editing, making it easy to open the file in the separate dev environment.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> is the most useful one. It's a meta shortcut

Answer (score 8):

Within the tool:
  "Help -> Default Keymap Reference"
(as suggested by [krosenvold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23691/krosenvold))

On the Internet:  ["IntelliJ IDEA Developers Documentation"](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/documentation.html)

Windows, Linux and Mac keyboard shortcut reference cards for versions 8, 7, 6, 5, and 4.5.

*(I **knew** I had seen and used these reference "cards" before!  ;-)*

One of my favorites *(not shown on the JetBrains cards)* is "**Ctrl+Shift+**{Up or Down **Arrow**}" to move lines/methods up and down in the source code.

See also ["Intellij Idea Keyboard Shortcuts" page on Ward's Wiki](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?IntellijIdeaKeyboardShortcuts).

Comment: Yes!  I was looking for the "move up and down" command.

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> deletes the entire line (will 'cut' it to clipboard)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to reformat and optimize imports

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join lines (pull content of next line up to current line).

Comment: Shift+delete will also put the cut data to clipboard

Comment: Ctrl+X also cuts a whole line to the clipboard if no text is selected

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> - switches to [column selection mode](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html), allowing the selection of rectangular text fragments (columns)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> - go to most recent code edit. Hit again to go even further back. Very useful when coding something, browsing other classes for a while and then wanting to go back where we left our code.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> - recently opened files

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> - recently edited files

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> - paste one of the previous values from clipboard

Comment: How do you switch to column selection mode on a Mac? (Many Mac keyboards don't have an insert key.)

Comment: Just with pressed mouse wheel ;-)

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> invokes a dialog with all alphanumeric keys on the keyboard. Selecting one empty will add the current line to bookmarks and mark the line with selected key.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> invokes a list of bookmarks. Pressing a key takes to associated bookmark.

Answer (score 5):

One of my real favorites may not count as a keyboard shortcut exactly. But the "iter" smart template is really great.

basically if you want to iterate though something using a for loop type "iter" then tab to use the live template

iter<kbd>tab</kbd>

it will figure out the most likely variable you want to iterate over and generate a for loop for it. I'm pretty sure it uses the nearest reference to an object which supports iteration.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> - automatically completes the code statement you are typing, inserting the quotation marks, brackets, curly braces and other punctuation as necessary.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>F7</kbd> <kbd>F8</kbd> <kbd>F9</kbd>   for debugging

Answer (score 2):

If you are coming from Eclipse:
http://tanu.wordpress.com/2010/09/24/moving-from-eclipse-to-intellij-idea/

General documentation and shortcuts are on Intellij's site
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/index.jsp

Answer (score 1):

Any combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> in idea8 is also excellent.

There is a complete keymap in the online help too.

Comment: The "N" shortcuts would be (mostly) "Navigate to" actions:

Navigation
  Ctrl + N               = Go to class
  Ctrl + Shift + N       = Go to file
  Ctrl + Alt + Shift + N = Go to symbol

Plus, as an added bonus, one of my personal favorites:
  Ctrl + Alt + N = Refactor Inline

Ctrl + Shift + T = go to test class (or class under test, from test class)

Yep; see "Help -> Default Keymap Reference".

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> : Open class.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> : Find usages.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/ReferenceCard70_mac.pdf has everything you need. after a while, you'll develop your own preference for certain shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

This link has everything you need.  Plus in Idea 8 atleast, every shortcut is completely customizable, so it's really up to you what the most useful ones are.

[Idea 8 reference PDF](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA8_ReferenceCard.pdf)