# What is Eclipse's Ctrl+O (Show Outline) shortcut equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-idea

I like to use Eclipse's shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> which outlines the current source. Is there an equivalent shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA?

It opens a dialog which allows for quick search of methods and fields in a class.

Comment: It would aid web searchers a lot if you included a description of the functionality you're after in this question's title. Eclipse's keyboard shortcuts are platform- and setup-dependent.

Answer (score 369, accepted):

I haven't used Eclipse for years, so I'm not that familiar with the behaviour you're after - but I believe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> may do what you want: it is the shortcut for the *File structure Popup* in the default mapping.

For macOS <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: See for more shortcuts. At StackOverflow : 

What are the most useful Intellij IDEA keyboard shortcuts?
AT

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294167/what-are-the-most-useful-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: For the record, `Ctrl-F12` is bound to the *File Structure* command, available in the top-level *Navigate* menu.

Comment: cmd + fn + F12 for OS X

Comment: @loeschg what if cmd + f12 is overridden by the system's volume up?

Comment: @LucianNut then you'll probably want cmd + fn + F12 like willy_z suggested.

Comment: CMD + 7 on Mac will show the structure (functions) pane. The same command will toggle it off.

Comment: Quick Outline (Ctrl + O) in eclipse VS File Structure Popup (Ctrl+ F12) (in windows)

Answer (score 41):

Shortcuts:

- Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>
- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>
- Ubuntu/CentOS: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>

Answer (score 16):

Windows : <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

MacOS : <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

Above commands will show the functions/methods in the **current class**.

Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> TWO times if you want to search both class and method in the whole project.

Comment: This wont work as sometimes you want to search in small sample space.

Comment: It is not the answer to the posted question. CTRL+O in eclipse searches in current class/file. CTRL+F12 is the correct equivalent.

Comment: The scope is too wide for double shift based search in IntelliJ

Answer (score 11):

For Intellij 13 on ubuntu the shortcut for the Structure window is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> on Mac).  You can make the window floating to simulate the Eclipse behavior using the top-right setting icon, also unselect the pinned mode option for <kbd>Esc</kbd> to work.

Comment: The other solutions (Ctrl/Cmd-O) show methods but cannot show fields.

Answer (score 11):

On MacOSX 10.8.5, <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> did not work for me. I had to use <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: depends upon the preferences you have set for your mac machine

Comment: Is the Fn necesssary to reveal the F1-12 keys on your macbook pro with touchbar? You can configured that in the Keyboard System Preferences i.e. always show F keys on the touchbar when in Intellij

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> in Idea is the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> in Eclipse.

The thread is old. Just thought might be useful for someone lookin for the same answer...

Comment: Ctrl-F3 is correct IF you're using the Eclipse keymap in IntelliJ IDEA.  If you're using the default IntelliJ keymap, it's Ctrl-F12.  At least in IDEA 10.

Comment: In what I believe is a default keymap, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> is "Find word at caret".

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> or search "File Structure" in keymap

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> works for me. I'm using intellij IDEA CE 12 with default keymap.

Answer (score 4):

All these answers are subjective, because they depend on your platform, keymap and IntelliJ version.

I believe the 'Structure' tool is what you're looking for. In Idea 13, *View* → *Tool Windows* → *Structure* will open the view, and along the way, the menu will show you the applicable keyboard shortcut for your setup.

Answer (score 4):

For me, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> Works really well!

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> mimics the same functionality.
 
You can also use [this link](https://www.catalysts.cc/en/wissenswertes/intellij-idea-and-eclipse-shortcuts/) which gives *Eclipse* and corresponding *IntelliJ IDEA* shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

For some **Linux** kinds, and particularly for **XFCE** (like Xubuntu, Mint XFCE) a lot of default XWin keyboard layout **mappings are not working**.

This is because they overlap with assigned *Window Manager* -> *Keyboard* shortcuts.
For the concrete question <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> is assigned to *Workspace 12* which I doubt that many use at all.

The **solution** is to clear those Window manager assignments in *Window Manager* -> *Keyboard* tab. As a temporal workaround you may use IDEA actions via *Find action* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

There are other overlapping short keys. References:

- [Difference between Default and Default XWin keymaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51331998)
- [Avoid shortcut conflicts in Linux keymap](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7658?)
- [File structure on CTRL+F12 dissapeared in 13.1.5](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206840705-File-structure-on-CTRL-F12-dissapeared-in-13-1-5-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a persistent/sticky/docked Tool Window instead of a temporary/transient dialog:

- *Mac*: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I think [here](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/getting-started-with-intellij-idea-as-an-eclipse-user/4/) you can found out the most useful shortcuts for Idea as an Eclipse user... 
Eclipse "Quick outline" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (Windows) is an equivalent Idea "File Structure" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>!

Comment: Link only answers are not useful as they don't guarantee a future user can find the answer. Please include a summary of the information in your answer.

Comment: You are right, I didn't think about that... just include some info.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use eclipse keymap in intellij by clicking <kbd>ALT</kbd>+ <kbd>→</kbd> keymap. Then select eclipse keymap.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> works, because it is for file structure popup, which is similar to showing code in *Eclipse*.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, I'm using XFCE from windows to remote Ubuntu and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> doesn't work. Since no one mentioned recombine, I'd like to share my solution.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>` to open settings.
- Click `Keymap`
- Input `file structure` in search box
- Right click the item and click `Add Keyboard Shortcut`
- Press keyboard combination you like and I used Ctrl + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> since I came from Eclipse world. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> has been bound already, so I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> instead

Now, you can use Ctrl + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> to trigger the file structure.

For details about keymap rebinding, please refer to [this thread](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html).

Answer (score -3):

The shortcuts are:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for files
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for classes

Answer (score -8):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> is the one you're looking for.

Comment: That brings up a "Reformat Code" dialog for me, using what I believe are default keyboard bindings.

Comment: @LuigiR.Viggiano Doesn't ⌘+F12 is overridden by the System's Volume UP command? Or do you know a way avoid it?

Comment: Yes, you can change OS X shortcuts, I think in keyboard settings, but don't remember now.

Comment: @DenisWeerasiri You need to hold the Fn-button to hit the F-buttons on a Mac. So ⌘+F12 is the same as ⌘+Fn+VolumeUp