# What is the shortcut in IntelliJ IDEA to find method / functions?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I know that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> is to find classes and it is very useful. But what about methods?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Eclipse's Ctrl+O shortcut equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945213/what-is-eclipses-ctrlo-shortcut-equivalent-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: It is similar, but it is not exactly the same function. (?)

Comment: For me it is Alt-Cmd-O, Select Navigate->Symbol menu item. Next to it you can see your shortcut.

Answer (score 357, accepted):

Windows : <kbd>^ ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

MacOS : <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

Above commands will show the functions/methods in the **current class**.

Press <kbd>⇧ SHIFT</kbd> TWO times if you want to search both class and method in the whole project.

Comment: If you type "sudo grep something /" you can also find anything, on your whole computer :)

Comment: @olafure ,yes you can. "sudo grep something /" will search in whole computer and give lot of unnecessary results also will take lot of extra time. So, it's better to search something in IDE only.

Comment: I believe that's his point... When looking for methods using the option that will even find text results in files outside of the project is a bit heavy-handed.

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, it's what I've been trying to avoid since I don't want to search multiple files which might have the same method name. the Ctrl+F12 method below with like 3x as many upvotes is what should be marked as the correct answer...

Comment: Does not work on Intellij 15.x version for methods (brings lot of clutter but methods) - also it makes sense to use a direct method navigation search for code that is familiar. You can directly jump to a known method name. I think the answer below is better choice.

Comment: what is difference between this and Ctrl+Alt+Shift+N  ?

Comment: while this is correct, double shift is terrible at finding method names. It also finds classes and filenames and probably coins under your seat as well.

Comment: Also press it FOUR times to include non-project related items.

Comment: Double shift is very useful, but is not what was asked. The answer of Daniel Deng is the correct one

Comment: For the sake of completeness, in KDE it's CTRL + 0.

Answer (score 812):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> on macOS) will show all members of the current class in a popup window and let you pick up one. It works exactly like the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> shortcut in eclipse, much faster than <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>

Comment: now I use mac. Do you know the equivalent shortcut for mac? Thanks!

Comment: Cmnd f12 on mac. I think this is a better answer.

Comment: Cmnd + ALT + O is also very useful on macs, to find symbols.

Comment: hmmm. Cmd+Alt+O actually leads me to optimize imports. Cmd+alt+shift+n does it though..maybe it depends on the version, I'm on 12.1.4

Comment: @Siddhartha, you need to change your config to fit Mac-style shortcuts. But everything changes.

Comment: What's the name of action to show all members of the current class?

Comment: In fact in Eclipse this is Ctrl+O (Quick Outline). Ctrl+Shift+O is for Organize imports.

Comment: This is what I was looking for

Comment: This is awesome because I was only finding answers for searching across the whole project, which is a waste of time when you're searching for a method like "init" or "destroy". Thank you!!

Comment: Works on Intellij 15.x version for me. This should be the right answer.

Comment: @sealskej it's called "File Structure" on the keymap setting.

Comment: Please include the name of the action in the answer for people with different hotkeys

Answer (score 106):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> allows you to search for symbols, including methods.

The primary advantage of this more complicated keybinding is that is searches in all files, not just the current file as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> does.

(And as always, for Mac you substitute <kbd>Cmd</kbd> for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for these keybindings.)

Comment: Thank you very much! And how can I find this option on menus?

Comment: I found it! It is under Go To menu. Easy!

Comment: Does not work for me on mac. Although CMD+ F12 works. Thanks

Comment: Ctrl + F12  worked nice for me. Intelli IDEA J 2018.2

Answer (score 17):

### Android Studio on Mac

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

Opens up the **Symbol** lookup that you can jump to most of the methods/functions in your currently opened document.

Comment: The results displayed using this key combination aren't restricted to the currently open document. For that, cmnd+f12 is what you want (per the answer by Daniel Dang and comment by Thomas).

Comment: For complete clarity, what exactly is the definition of "Symbol" in terms of Android Studio?

Comment: @ImpalaTamer Good question. I use it to jump to methods, functions and definitions mostly but it looks like it could bring up more than that.

Comment: For those wondering, this action is called "File Structure" in Actions search menu.

Answer (score 16):

**Intellij IDEA 2017.3.4 - 2018.2** (Ultimate) on OSX

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

will show all members of the current class in a popup window, then you can search method in that class.

**BUT**, this answer is depends on your Keyboard setting. If your keyboard setting in

**System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys**

is selected, then the shortcut becomes

<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>

Comment: I think this should be the correct reply as it gets you to the methods window only, where with further shortcuts we can also see inherited, anonymous and lambdas. Powerful and cool! Thanks

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> brings up the File Structure navigation menu, which lets you search for members of the currently open file.

Answer (score 7):

IntelliJ IDEA Version 12.13 Ultimate Edition:

Macs:
<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
or on Menu -> Navigate > Symbol ...

Comment: Did not work for me this option. Here in Mac is command + option + O

Comment: It depends on the keymap you choose in "Preference->Keymap" . it seems you choose the "Mac OS X 10.5+"

Answer (score 7):

Slightly beside the actual question, but nonetheless useful: The Help menu of Intellij has an option 'Default Keymap reference', which opens a PDF with the complete mapping. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> is mentioned there)

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to look for methods:

On mac OS X 10.5+ binding, it is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

By Default XWin Key binding, it is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

You can also press double <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> then, you can search anything (not only method, but also class, files, and actions)

Comment: I've removed the tutorial URL. Please don't include the URLs that could be considered as spam.

Answer (score 5):

It is worth adding that if you want to search for a method of a class, you can use a `.` (dot) between the class and method name inside of either the search everywhere or search symbols dialog. This even works with IDEAs usual search benefits. For example, you can search for `LDT.now` and `LocalDateTime::now` will pop up as a result. (As long as you are searching All Files and not just Project Files).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you click on a method, you can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to go to that method's declaration.  Similar to <kbd>F12</kbd> in MS Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

If I need navigate to method in currently opened class, I use this combination: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> on Mac) to open structure view, and press two times (first time open, second time focus on view), type name of methods, select on of needed.

Answer (score 2):

To Find the actions build in the IDEA(reindent, create new, ...) you can use

<kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

then type indent for example and ENTER.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij v 13.1.4, OSX

The Open Symbol keyboard shortcut is 
<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>7</kbd> after selecting the method

Answer (score 0):

I tried <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>

But I think the most powerful and easy to use feature is find in all files <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Choose **regex** and write `.*partOfMethodName.*\(` and it shows all places and can see the actual source code **in place** without going to that specific file.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + F12 and type method name. once you type method name, input text box will appear for same.

In IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.2 or greater version