# IntelliJ shortcut to show a popup of methods in a class that can be searched

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm switching over from Eclipse to IntelliJ. In Eclipse, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in the editor, shows a hover popup that allows to search for a method in the class you're editing.

What is the equivalent shortcut for that in IntelliJ?

Comment: Just realized this is a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945213/what-is-eclipses-ctrlo-shortcut-equivalent-in-intellij-idea

Comment: You can also have the exact same keymap with Eclipce in IntelliJ.

Comment: If you are used to Eclipse, you can directly use the eclipse shortcuts : press Ctrl + Shift + A , Search Keymap and select Eclipse. All IntelliJ shortcuts will be transformed to Eclipse shortcuts.

Now do a Ctrl + O :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Eclipse's Ctrl+O (Show Outline) shortcut equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945213/what-is-eclipses-ctrlo-show-outline-shortcut-equivalent-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 737, accepted):

Use **Navigate** (**View** in older versions) | **File Structure Popup** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> on Windows,
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> on OS X). Start typing method/symbol name to either narrow down the list or highlight the desired element. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to navigate to the selected element.

Comment: Very nice, I'm looking for a pop-up that searches throughout the whole project (like Ctrl+Alt+M in Eclipse) and not just current file (like Ctrl+O in Eclipse), any ideas ?

Comment: `Go To` | `Symbol...` is most likely what you are looking for.

Comment: On Mac OS X, IntelliJ v12 this is now Cmnd+F12

Comment: Cmd + 7 on Mac will also show methods pane permanently. Cmd + 7 again will toggle it off.

Comment: This action has been moved to **Navigate | File Structure**.

Answer (score 123):

I prefer to use the Structure view.  To open it, use the menu: View/Tools Window/Structure.
The hotkey on Windows is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>,
<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> on OS X

Comment: Never knew about this until today. Thank you. Now I don't have to wonder where F12 is on my mac keyboard.

Answer (score 26):

Do <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> Key on mac in IntelliJ if clicking <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> starts.

Answer (score 9):

On linux distributions (@least on Debian with plasma) the default shortcut is

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> (zero)

Comment: This brought a `Select methods to Override` window for me in Ubuntu 19.10.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running on Linux (I tested in Ubuntu 10.04), the shortcut is Ctrl + F12 (same of Windows)

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> is correct. 
Lacking of button <kbd>fn</kbd> the <kbd>F12</kbd> is used adjust the volume.

Answer (score 3):

By default, most of distribution uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.

Some OS distribution (in my case Xubuntu) which uses Xcfe, overrides <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to "Workspace 12" switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can type "`this.`" and wait a second, a popup with methods and properties will display.

Not a shortcut, but it works for me.

PS: if you are in a static method, type the class name.

Comment: I like your approach :)

Comment: I really don't understand the negatives. My method is the only one who works on every IntelliJ version, computer or customization. Think about that

Comment: @Telcontar: I guess that people gave you the downvotes because the original question was "What is the equivalent shortcut for **that** in IntelliJ" where **that** was described quite precisely :) Your "answer" is rather a comment.

Comment: I don't understand why there are so many down votes.  "this." is a good alternative.  I do that often.  I was also an Eclipse user before moving to intellij and I did the same on Eclipse too.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac Users if `command + fn + f12` or `command + f12` is not working, then your key map is not selected as "Mac Os X". To select key map follow the below steps.

```
Android Studio -> Preferences -> Keymap -> From the drop down Select "Mac OS X" -> Click Apply -> OK.
```

Answer (score -3):

Ashkan Kh. Nazary  you can use

> Ctrl+N 
>   or
>   Ctrl+Shift+N

source  [IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)