# PhpStorm equvalent for Open Method (Ctrl + Shift + M) in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, phpstorm

There is a nice shortcut in Eclipse that brings up a dialog with all methods and functions available (shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>), is there an equivalent in PhpStrom ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990289/intellij-shortcut-to-show-a-popup-of-methods-in-a-class-that-can-be-searched/3992371#3992371.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Go To` | `Symbol...` is most likely what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for replying here again so I can mark your answer as correct

Comment: As a keyboard shortcut for Go To (or Navigate) | Symbol:
`Ctrl + Alt + Shift + N`