# Android Studio/Intellij Idea: "Table of Contents" for a class

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I have been messing around with Android Studio and so far I like most of what I have seen. One thing that has been annoying me though is this lack of "Table of Contents" for a class. I apologize for not knowing exactly what to call it. But what I am referring to is the dropdown menu in eclipse that lists all the methods, interfaces, classes and so on that are in that class file. This then allows you to jump to that position. This view is when you are in "Package Explorer" and click the arrow to the left of the class. This is one thing that makes me really miss eclipse. I know that you can easily search with `Ctrl+F` inside a document but I often forget the method names. I tried looking through [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) but to no avail. Just wondering if anyone knows some way to handle this.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/3992371/104891.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

IDEA has a tab called "Structure", which shows all the methods, fields, etc. of the currently-open class.

[image: IDEA window with Structure tab]

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Too bad I couldn't have figured it out on my own.

Comment: I wonder why they could not have implemented a pulldown list to jump to a method, in that breadcrumb style navigation just under the main toolbar, like QtCreator, XCode and others do. Would have been so much more convenient.

Comment: I was able to drag "Structure" to the right side of the UI. Now I can see the class structure and the project structure at the same time - like I had it in Eclipse.

Comment: CMD + O in Eclipse is like fn + CMD + F12 in Android Studio !

Comment: @jazzyjester you deserve the correct answer. **CMD+F12**  awesome. Using 'Fn' key depends on the Keyboard model though.

Comment: It's hidden in the menu under "View" -> "Tool Windows" -> "Structure", an if you're searching for a way to shift it to the right: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html#move

Answer (score 51):

I've just got a Tip of the Day popup in Android Studio helping with exactly this problem.

> You can quickly navigate in the currently edited file with
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>**+**<kbd>F12</kbd> (Navigate | File Structure).
>
> It shows the list of members of the current class. Select an element you want to navigate to and press the Enter key or the F4 key. To easily locate an item in the
>   list, just start typing its name.

Also, as *danny117* points out, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>**+**<kbd>7</kbd> to show / hide the same content in a side panel view (shown above in *Chris Jester-Young's* answer).

Comment: I just want to ping in alt+7

Comment: For `File structure` just cmd + F12

Comment: Yep, that's what the post says :)

Answer (score 14):

View > Tool Windows > Structure

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what `Chris Jester-Young` said, it's worth pointing out how to see the methods and properties of a class pointed by the cursor.

**a)** Type `Ctrl + H` in the class pointed by cursor.

**b)** In the class name, in the *hierarchy window*, double-click the class name. The system, upon confirmation, will decompile and open the class code.

**c)** `Alt + 7` (Windows) or `Command + 7` (MAC) to display the *structure window*.

**d)** One can now visualize properties, methods, derived classes, derived interfaces, and even include inherited items. All related to the class under the caret.

Comment: Also very useful.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using Beta 0.8.9 of the Android Studio and what you need to do is click on the settings icon in the [Android Project View](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-androidview.html). If you select 'Show Members' then the Classes become expandable and you can navigate around the class using the project view.