# Jump between Methods in Android Studio like Visual Studio/Eclipse

Tags: android, android-studio

In Visual Studio when you open a CLASS or something it gives you the chance to just select from a DROPDOWN menu to quickly jump down to a specific method inside the class.

I know in Eclipse they have the OUTLINE window on the right hand side that shows up sometimes also that gives a more generic way of doing this.

What about Android Studio?  How would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IntelliJ shortcut to show a popup of methods in a class that can be searched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990289/intellij-shortcut-to-show-a-popup-of-methods-in-a-class-that-can-be-searched)

Comment: cmd+F12 opens the file structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Android Studio you can use for this purpose Structure Window (Alt+7)

Answer (score 2):

You have following options to jump to a specific method or jump between methods in Android Studio:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>: This will open Structure Window where you can find all methods.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>: This will open a dialog, similar to Structure Window, where you can find all methods. Also it has filter option. Start typing method name and it will filter out methods.
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>: Using this  you can jump between methods.

Answer (score 2):

Mac: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> but I had to disable the default shortcuts for Mission Control and Application windows in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control