# IntelliJ idea and duplicate class issue

Tags: intellij-idea

The dev env unfortunately is such that it creates a duplicate java file in a hidden directory under the same original root for every .java file. This is just a backup mechanism and can't change it. Good thing is this hidden dir name is same. I have Excluded this dir name pattern in the Settings of Intellij IDEA community edition 10.x. Yet, IDE reports this class as a duplicate one. Usages/References as well.

Bonus Q: Is there an eclipse equivalent of Ctrl-O in **my** IDEA to quickly navigate to methods?

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one. It's convenient for you but makes your question less useful to others looking for the same things in the future.

Answer (score 4):

How exactly did you exclude it? It should be added to the list of ignored folders in Settings | File Types. If it doesn't work, [file a bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA).

> Bonus Q: Is there an eclipse equivalent of Ctrl-O in my IDEA to quickly navigate to methods?

[Already replied here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990289/intellij-shortcut-to-show-a-popup-of-methods-in-a-class-that-can-be-searched/3992371#3992371) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945213/what-is-eclipses-ctrlo-shortcut-equivalent-in-intellij-idea). Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>.