# Difference between Default and Default XWin keymaps

Tags: intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA on Linux and I noticed 2 keymaps who look very similar : Default and Default XWin.

Which one should I use on Linux and what are the differences?
And is it possible to compare keymaps (to compare Default KDE and Default XWin for example).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the differences between some of the keymaps

```
+-----------------------------------+----------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|                                   |    Default     | Default for GNOME | Default for XWin | Default for KDE |
+-----------------------------------+----------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+
| Build Project                     | Ctrl+F9        |                   |                  | Ctrl+9          |
| Run to Cursor                     | Alt+F9         | Alt+Shift+9       |                  | Alt+Shift+9     |
| Force Run to Cursor               | Ctrl+Alt+F9    | Ctrl+Alt+9        | Ctrl+Alt+9       | Ctrl+Alt+9      |
| Show Execution Point              | Alt+F10        | Alt+Shift+0       |                  | Alt+Shift+0     |
| Evaluate Expression...            | Alt+F8         | Alt+Shift+8       |                  | Alt+Shift+8     |
| Stop                              | Ctrl+F2        |                   |                  | Ctrl+2          |
| Toggle Line Breakpoint            | Ctrl+F8        |                   |                  | Ctrl+8          |
| Esc                               | Ctrl+Shift+F4  |                   |                  | Ctrl+Shift+4    |
|                                   | Ctrl+F4        |                   |                  | Ctrl+4          |
| Find Word at Caret                | Ctrl+F3        |                   |                  | Ctrl+3          |
| View Breakpoints...               | Ctrl+Shift+F8  |                   |                  | Ctrl+Shift+8    |
| Go to File Member                 | Ctrl+F12       |                   |                  | Ctrl+0          |
| Change Signature...               | Ctrl+F6        |                   |                  | Ctrl+6          |
| Find Usages / Find Usages in File | Alt+F7         | Alt+Shift+7       |                  | Alt+Shift+7     |
|                                   | Ctrl+F7        | Ctrl+F7           |                  | Ctrl+7          |
| Highlight Usages in File          | Ctrl+Shift+F7  |                   |                  | Ctrl+Shift+7    |
| Introduce Variable                | Ctrl+Alt+V     |                   |                  | Alt+Shift+V     |
| Show Usages                       | Ctrl+Alt+F7    | Ctrl+Alt+7        | Ctrl+Alt+7       | Ctrl+Alt+7      |
| Show Error Description            | Ctrl+F1        |                   |                  | Ctrl+1          |
| Select In...                      | Alt+F1         |                   |                  | Alt+Shift+1     |
| Reformat Code                     | Ctrl+Alt+L     |                   |                  | Alt+Shift+L     |
| Navigate Back/Forward             | Ctrl+Alt+Left  | Alt+Shift+Left    |                  |                 |
|                                   | Ctrl+Alt+Right | Alt+Shift+Right   |                  |                 |
+-----------------------------------+----------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

[This table in markdown](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/7355e0ed2f739a8a611f153901b4b808)

I found out the differences between the keymaps in jetbrains suite of tools by

1. Exporting the keymaps to pdf with [Keymap Exporter](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7066-keymap-exporter) plugin
2. Converting the pdf to text with [pdftotext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext)
3. Diffing the resulting text files

Answer (score 4):

for example, `Edit -> Find -> Show Usages` in Default, shortcut is `Ctrl+Alt+F7`,
but in Linux, `Ctrl+Alt+F7` will switch to tty7,
so in Default XWin, the shortcut should change to `Ctrl+Alt+7`

Comment: Which keymap set has the least amount of overlap with Ubuntu's native hotkeys?

Comment: @anon58192932 I think you can check the hotkey setting in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

A difference that I found in debugging: on Ubuntu with xfce as GUI, if Keymap is set as Default XWin, Alt+Left Click to evalute the expression or variable value will not work as usual. Setting the Keymap to Default works perfectly.

Also see: [Intellij Idea alt + click to evaluate debugger code not working in Mint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701384/intellij-idea-alt-click-to-evaluate-debugger-code-not-working-in-mint)