# Intellij Idea alt + click to evaluate debugger code not working in Mint

Tags: intellij-idea, linux-mint

On Windows, and I think Mac, holding `alt + left click` on a section of code when paused in the debugger will evaluate the expression and show the value in a tooltip. It's much more convenient than `alt + f8` and `ctrl + alt + 8`.

In Linux Mint, holding alt and clicking doesn't do anything (I've disabled Mint's "Special key to move and resize windows").

Is there a way to map it to `alt + left click`, or a different key combination to evaluate an expression by clicking on it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found it mapped to `ctrl + alt + shift + left click` under `Quick Evaluate Expression` as a Mouse Shortcut.

Comment: Thx from 2022 <3

Answer (score 8):

Settings -> keymap, change from "Default for XWin" to "Default"

Answer (score 0):

For everyone searching for a solution why alt-click is not working on Linux Mint, even if it is configured correctly in IntelliJ. Nathanial mentioned it in his question:

In Linux Mint windows could be moved around by holding Alt+left and moving the mouse around. After disabling this feature, alt-click started working again in IntelliJ.

Open the settings in Linux Mint and choose "window". Then in the middle tab change the special key defined for "move and resize window" from "alt" to anything else.

[image]
[image]