# How to make autocomplete show methods suggestions for overriding at subclass context on Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Say I have:

```
public class A extends B {
  /* autocompletion doesn't suggests protected methods from B to 
     override with Ctrl+SPACE
  */
}
```

I'm currently using Intellij IDEA 11.0.2.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Right click in your editor pane for class `A`, go to 'Generate...' -> 'Override Methods...'.

You'll then be presented with a list of all methods that can be overridden.

'Generate...' can also be called up via keyboard shortcuts, I'm on a Mac currently and it's `^N`. IIRC the shortcut on Windows/Linux is Alt-Insert.

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently on Linux, the shortcut to the 'Override Methods' is CTRL + O as MalsR said in his answer above.

Comment: This is stupid, not your answer, why don't they make it autocomplete for you like how Xcode does it.

Answer (score 12):

Tried to add this as a comment but the keyboard shortcuts are clear when added as a reply ;)

Once in your subclass do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> (Windows) this will list the methods that you can override, which includes the standard ones as well as the methods from your superclass.

**Additional Info (Not related to question):** Also posted a link that contains some other very useful intelliJ shorcuts if they are of use to you. [IntelliJ shortcuts that I can't find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213546/intellij-shortcuts-that-i-cant-find)

Comment: Thank you MalsR for the shortcut tip (which also is the same at Linux). Also thank you for the link. I will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

On Mac with the latest Intellij (13), use `Code > Override Methods...` and start to type the method you want to override, it will automatically generate the whole method with the `@Override` annotation for you

The shortcut for this is `Cmd + O`