# Command shortcut in intellij-idea

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In eclipse by typing "main" and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> you can generate `main` method, and there are lots of other shortcuts like this.
Is there anything like this in intellij-idea? and how can I assign them?

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon your key configuration, you can type <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> for the Templates.

Also see: [What are the most useful Intellij IDEA keyboard shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294167/what-are-the-most-useful-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just type sout and press tab button the main method with complete signature will be generated for you.

Answer (score 0):

By default configuration shortcut for `public static void main(String args[])` is:

`psvm` + `TAB`

`psvm` stands for **P**ublic **S**tatic **V**oid **M**ain