# XCode's equivalent shortcut for Eclipse's QuickFix/Intellij's Show Action Intetion

Tags: ios, eclipse, xcode, intellij-idea, xcode5

In both Eclipse and IntelliJ, when you have a warning/error you could do `Ctrl+1` in [Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98220/what-is-your-favorite-hot-key-in-eclipse#answer-98885) or `Alt+Enter` in [IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294167/what-are-the-most-useful-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts?rq=1#answer-295066) to popup a menu of suggested actions and quick fixes.

What is the equivalent shortcut in XCode?

Comment: XCode appears to have a feature called "Fix-it": https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/Fix-it.html