# Android: Android Studio vs. Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I want to make my first android application and i'm new to `Android` world, i have seen so many tutorials and videos about android development, some say `Android Studio` is better and some say `Eclipse` is the core that all android apps is built with.

I'm confused here, which one should i work on in my android development learning and first app ?

**Note** I already followed a tutorial that uses `Eclipse` so i know something about `Eclipse`, and i have no idea what `Android Studio` is like.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Choosing an IDE is a matter of personal preference. Try both of those out and see which one you like better. Personally, I am a big fan of IntelliJ (Android Studio is based off IntelliJ) and I hate Eclipse but your preferences may be different than mine.

Comment: "some say" -- it is important, when reading things (particularly on the Internet) to check the age of the information. Blog posts, Stack Overflow answers, and the like from 2+ years ago would all be talking about Eclipse, because Android Studio had not yet been announced, let alone released in stable form.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio is now the official IDE according to the docs:

https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html

In the long run you will probably get better support, official and community, for it.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing more , nothing less

[Android Studio is the official IDE for Android application development, based on IntelliJ IDEA.](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Download Android Studio and give it a try. I promise you that you will not ever be programming Android apps in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

**Eclipse vs Android Studio**

Google released Android Studio for android development and stop developing android plugin for eclipse. In this document developers will put their opinion about why we should use Eclipse/Android Studio. If Android Studio provide us better support for development, then we will switch to Android Studio after 2.1 release.

**Why Android Studio:**

Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android. [ ref. https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html ]

Projects are much easier to main.

Eclipse is OK when you are developing smaller applications, but when your application has 10 projects and 20 external libraries, that's when the fun begins – refresh project, clean project, restart Eclipse, and then all over again. But, in android studio all you need is press “sync” button, you never had to worry about adding jars after jars in your libs folder.

Oh! wait did I forgot to mention how you maintain different version of those jars in eclipse ?

Android studio use Gradle based build system. [ ref. http://gradle.org/ ]
NDK Support now available, and with gradle it’s much more easier now to compile, build, link your shared object files [.so] in your project.
Android Studio comes complete with support for JUnit unit and Android tests.

All the jetbrain keyboard shortcuts are available in android studio, and you can modify them according to your need.

[ref. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/keyboard-shortcuts-and-mouse-reference.html ,
[What are the most useful Intellij IDEA keyboard shortcuts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294167/what-are-the-most-useful-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts)  ]

Answer (score 0):

I used both.You had better use android studio.It is definitely better than eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Well personally i prefer the official Android IDE which is `Android Studio` off-course for those reasons:

1. It's made by jetBrains and *Google* *(you know, the developer of android)*.
2. It's very intelligent, it's like you're working with a bot.
3. Google has full documentations and examples on how to use literally anything in Android Studio.
4. I don't know if you're still looking for reason number 4 by far :) .

**Final Words** Use Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

I started with Eclipse and moved onto Android Studio. In my opinion Android Studio is way better than Eclipse! Also Android Studio is activly being developed and with the gradel build system its super easy to use lib from maven central. I will suggest Studio will be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio is often preferred for a number of reasons, many of which have been given here. However, the biggest reason is this:

It's not Eclipse.